# how to tell scons to compile .src files like .c files

Tags: scons

am using scons with renesas compiler.

in my project i need to compile .c, .s and .src files.

i am able to compile .c and .s files.

but if scons found the .src file it is skipping the file

can anyone help me to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: to whoever marked down, please say why this is a bad question

Comment: Seems to be a valid question, I dont understand why it was downvoted either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you'll need to add this extension to `env['CPPFILESUFFIXES']` to get `.src` files to be scanned for header dependencies.

Secondly, sadly, although fortran allows you to supply a list of extensions, C doesn't, so you'll have to define your own builder which mimics the C builder

Comment: Hi Tom Tanner

Thanks for your answer. i added one supperate builder to compile the .src files in my project. now it is working fine. thanks.

srctoobj_build = Builder(action = '$ASCOM', suffix = '.obj')
env.Append(BUILDERS = {'Srcfile_build' : srctoobj_build})

sources = env.Srcfile_build(srcfilelist)

Comment: Hi 
i created a new builder.
It is compiling perfectly the .src files. my problem is while compiling it is not taking the Given COMSTR string. how to do that.

Comment: thats a new question. Please therefore submit a new question, with example code